# R-MLR : get tuned hyperparameters for a wrapped learner

Tags: hyperparameters, mlr

I'm building an `xgboost` classification task in R using the `mlr` package :

```
# define task
Task <- mlr::makeClassifTask(id = "classif.xgboost",
                             data = df, 
                             target = "response", 
                             weights = NULL, 
                             positive = "yes", 
                             check.data = TRUE,
                             blocking = folds)

# make a base learner
lrnBase <- makeLearner(cl = "classif.xgboost", 
                       predict.type = "prob", 
                       # "response" (= labels) or "prob" (= labels and probabilities)
                       predict.threshold = NULL
                       )
```

I have to undersample one of my classes :

```
lrnUnder <- makeUndersampleWrapper(learner = lrnBase, usw.rate = 0.2, usw.cl = "no")
```

I also have to tune some of the learner's hyperparameters:

```
paramSet <- makeParamSet(makeNumericParam(id = "eta", lower = 0.005, upper = 0.4),
                         makeIntegerParam(id = "nrounds", lower = 1, upper = 100))

tuneControl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 100)
resampin <- makeResampleDesc(method = "CV",
                             iters = 4L,
                             predict = "test")

lrnTune <- makeTuneWrapper(learner = lrnUnder,
                           resampling = resampin, 
                           measures = fp,
                           par.set = paramSet,
                           control = tuneControl)
```

**My first question** is that how can I get the **FINAL tuned hyper-parameters** (and not tuned hyper-parametrs corresponding to each iteration of CV so not by `extract` argument) ? In the `mlr` tutorial I found out that I have to `train` my model as follows :

```
mdl <- mlr::train(learner = lrnTune, task = Task)
getTuneResult(mdl)
```

but this does not work without a `nested resampling`. So when I add this block to my code it works :

```
resampout.desc <- makeResampleDesc(method = "CV",
                                   iters = length(levels(folds)),
                                   predict = "both",
                                   fixed = TRUE)
resampout <- makeResampleInstance(desc = resampout.desc, task = Task)

resamp <- mlr::resample(learner = lrnTune,
                        task = Task,
                        resampling = resampout, # outer
                        measures = f1, 
                        models = FALSE,
                        extract = getTuneResult,
                        keep.pred = TRUE)
```

**My second question** is that, in principal, **do I have to wrap my learner** if I don't want to do a nested resampling (i.e evaluate the performance of my model) ? Or can I simply make a non-wrapped learner and perform my tuning using `tuneParams` ?

Thank you in advance for your help since I got a bit confused about the functionality of wrapped learners and the nested resampling.

Comment: You can use `tuneParams()` to tune a learner and then extract the best hyperparameters as described in the tutorial (https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/tune.html). You certainly don't have to wrap your learner; the point of doing this is so you can simply train a model without having to worry about what the hyperparameters are. You should do a nested resampling though as otherwise your performance estimated may be biased. Does that make it clear?

Comment: Thanks Lars for your answer. Just to be sure that I understood your answer well : so, I can do a non-wrapped under sampling first **and** then tune the hyperparameters using `tuneParams()` with no worries about the leakage from test to train data ? I ask this because `tuneParams` includes also a `resampling` argument.

Comment: Yes, as long as you're performing the undersampling as a completely separate step there should be no leakage from test to train.

Comment: Many thanks Lars. I tried it. 
- Is it normal that the tuned hyper parameters that I got from `tuneParams` are different from `makeTuneWrapper` ? 
- I even noticed that `makeTuneWrapper` does not give the same results when I shrink my `lower:upper` interval although the previously-found optimized hyper parameters are still in the shrank interval (the `seed` is set to a specific value.) Why is it like this ?

Comment: In principle that's certainly possible depending on your setup and how you're setting the seed. If you're getting very different results that might indicate that you need to run the tuning for more iterations.

Comment: I agree, I think I have to run it for a greater number of random since both hyper parameters and confusion-matrix results are different. Thanks again !

Comment: Cool, does that answer the questions you had?

Comment: yes, it does ! Thank you for your help. All is clear. I have just to find the proper number of iterations to find the non-changing tuned hyper parameters.

Comment: Lars, I passed some time on finding the proper number of iterations for tuning my hyper parameters. I however came across a case for which I could not find any explanations. Shall I address it in a new question ? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a new question. Make sure to post a complete reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuneParams() to tune a learner and then extract the best hyperparameters as described in the tutorial (https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/tune.html). You certainly don't have to wrap your learner; the point of doing this is so you can simply train a model without having to worry about what the hyperparameters are. You should do a nested resampling though as otherwise your performance estimated may be biased.